# Capture all javascript <script> requests serverside

Tags: javascript, load, apache2

Suppose I have a directory structure like so

```
/var/www
└── test.js
```

Probably the most common way to load scripts in javascript is via

```
<script src='test.js'></script>
```

Now suppose I am constantly moving files around. Now the directory structure looks like

```
/var/www
└── foobar
    └── test.js
```

Rather than going through every file and changing the paths to

```
<script src='foobar/test.js'></script>
```

I want to 'catch' the `<script>` request on the server (apache2), and look for the `test.js` file. This search would be very much like how the shell uses the `PATH` variable to search for commands. Is there anyway to do this?

Now before people start questioning my premise, let me state a two things:

-I can't control when the files are moved around, and where

-I **can** set up a php script to find the file and return the full path to the client, however, this would require one additional xmlhttprequest call.

---

**EDIT** The reason I need to capture all requests is to reduce the total number of requests. Currently, I am querying the server to find the full path name of the script (first request), and then I am passing that path name to `<script src=...>` (second request). Instead, what I want is to call `<script src='test.js'>`, then have the server look for 'test.js' in the current folder, and if that doesn't work, look in all other specified folders, in this case `foobar/`. Once it finds the script, it would return it, thus requiring only one request.

Comment: Why not have a simple include that has the correct paths to all the files you wish to load?

Comment: `cat /var/log/httpd/access_log|grep test.js`?

Comment: @Brad I mentioned that the files move around, and I can't control when they are moved around, and to where. I basically don't know where the files are.

Comment: @MarcB I don't know what you wish to accomplish there.

Comment: @puk, You mentioned that **you** move the files around, not that you don't know when, how, or where.  Unless you can explain more details about how you plan on finding these files, it is hard to help you.  My suggestion stands.  Do a simple include.  Maybe have this PHP script search a handful of folders for you, and output the necessary tags.

Comment: @puk: you wanted to capture all test.js requests. That comman looks for all test.js requests in the server's access log.

Comment: @Brad, there are a lot of scripts to load (>1000) and rather than force users to know exactly where the files are, I want a fallback so the user can type just the script name, and the server will look for it. Also, more than one user might move these files around and they may be referenced from more than one script

Comment: @MarcB failure to communicate: I want to capture all requests as they're made, not after.

Comment: @puk - Don't let your users move files around if they're used by other users. You say you can't control this - why not? It seems like a pretty odd setup.

Comment: @nnnnnn Well I wouldn't call it odd, perhaps 'unique', 'novel' or 'special'. I'm making a small API for users to create their own dynamic websites within a `/home` folder I assign them. I want them to create scripts and use them the same way users use shell programs. You would never chastise someone for requesting a `PATH` variable instead of typing out `/bin/echo` would you ;-)

Comment: What about a standard `[toplevel]/js` folder for common scripts that _you_ provide (assuming there are some), which would be readonly to the users, and then let each user put their own scripts in their own home folder? If you have the situation you described before where more than one user can move scripts then presumably more than one user can modify common scripts which could break other users' pages - surely that's not desirable?

Comment: @nnnnnn well for the permission issue, I am using suPHP, so members of the same group can edit shared files. If they set the permissions of a file to `0777`, then that's their own fault for being stupid.

Comment: @nnnnnn "and then let each user put their own scripts in their own home folder" yes that is how things are working now. I just wanted to emulate the shell search pattern (via `PATH`) in my API. NOTE: I already have this implemented, but it either has to make two requests, or be implemented via Ajax, and return the code as `javascript`, which gets evaled (`eval` is more efficient than `<script>`, but harder to debug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can  setup a .htaccess file that redirects all your `js` requests to one file. This way, all your scripts will be redirected to your serverside page that decides what js script to deliver based on the script's name :

htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.js$ server_side_script.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: My regex is a little rusty. I gather that means if the requested file name does not exist, if it is a `.js` file, redirect to `server_side_script.php`. But what is the `[NC,L]`

Comment: Also, what should `server_side_script.php` return? Should it simply `echo` the contents of the `.js` file?

Comment: well, those flags are not very important for your case. `NC` stands for not case sensitive and `L` for last. The server side should echo the contents of the targeted js file but not before setting the right headers  : `header("Content-type: text/javascript")`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I would know to do this is to setup a custom 404 handler.  The easiest way of creating one would be using an .htaccess file.  Add something like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /url.php
```

Then within url.php you would 'find' the .js file and output the contents.  Make sure to set the HTTP header to 200:

```
<?php
//
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
...
...
?>
```

The above assumes that when the page loads the .js file won't be initially found (which will launch the 404 handler).